# angularjs localization of data from database

Tags: angularjs, database, localization, angular-translate

I have implemented externalization for my angularjs application using 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/internationalization-of-angularjs-applications

In the same application I have some data, which I am getting from database by creating REST endpoints.

I want to know which is the optimized way for localized the data from database.

1. Should I create the translation values for the database data in json files like I do for the content in the views?
2. Should add additional locale values in the database table itself. For example, for each row that i created in english. If i have another locale as French. Then I would create another row in French.

Could you please suggest which is the better way ?

Please let me know if I have not mentioned any detail. I would update the post to clarify that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on which data you have in your database which you want to translate.

But most of the times i think it is a good idea to have several sets of masterdata in the database separated by a locale flag like 'en', 'ru', etc.

I do not think translations of database entries should be done in the client for one simple reason:

Idealy the client should not know anything about the data in the database and should not care about it either - the server should handle this. 
And the best solution for the server to do so most of the times is to have several entries in the database for each locale.

Comment: Thank you very much.. i was thinking on the same lines.